# HashTable in C++

Tags: c++

I need to implement a HashTable in C++. I thought of using Array. 
But i don't know exactly how to create an array of fixed size. 
Lets say that my class is named HT.
In the constructor i want  to specify the array size but i don't know how. 
I have a members  size_type size; and string [] t; in HT headerfile.
How can i specify the size of t from the constructor?

```
HT(size_type s):size(s) {

}
```

If it is not possible what data structure should i use to implement a hash table?

Comment: If you know the size at compile time you can use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array). If the size is not known until runtime you can use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Comment: Is i possible to use vector to implement a hashtable?
I will get the size as an argument to the constructor.

Comment: It is perfectly possible to implement a hashtable with a vector. Create a vector of arbitrary size by (for example) starting out with an empty vector and calling `push_back()` in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

In the Constructor for the `HT` class, pass in (or default to 0) a size variable (`s`) to specify the size of the array. Then set `t` to a new string array of size `s`

So something like:

```
 HT::HT(size_type s)
 {
     t = new string[s];
 }
```

Comment: But than i will have to delete it right?
should i use unique pointer?

Comment: From my experience, managing your pointers yourself is always ideal. But maybe someone with a bit more experience might have some more insight on when unique pointers are better to use

Comment: _Never_ manage pointers yourself unless **absolutely** necessary. I can't stress the **absolutely** enough. Look into RAII/SBRM and using smart pointers such as `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Really!? Why do people teach us one thing when the industry detest it! Cheers

Comment: Make sure that's actually what your professor is telling you. If they confirm they really meant you should use `new` and `delete` over RAII/SBRM they are straight up clueless.

Comment: It's probably a case of do it this way for now because its easier for us to teach you it

Comment: Don't settle for _probably_. If this person is clueless and teaching you bad habits what other terrible ideas are they planting in your head.

Answer (score 0):

You could do as std::array and make the size a compile-time parameter.

If not, there is really no use trying to avoid std::vector, since you'll be doing dynamic allocation no matter what.

So, while you **could**

```
struct HT
{ 
    HT(size_t size) : _size(size), _data(new std::string[size]) {}
private:
    size_t const _size;
    std::unique_ptr<std::string[]> _data;
};
```

It's only making your class more complex, less flexible and generally less elegant, so I'd go with vector:

```
#include <memory> 

using namespace std; 

struct HT
{ 
    HT(size_t size) : _size(size), _data(new std::string[size]) {}
  private:
    size_t const _size;
    std::unique_ptr<std::string[]> _data;
}; 

#include <vector> 
struct HT2
{ 
    HT2(size_t size) : _data(size) {}
  private:
    std::vector<std::string> _data;
}; 


int main()
{
    HT  table1(31);
    HT2 table2(31);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Most suggestions seem to assume it's ok to implement your hash table container class in terms of the standard library.  I wonder exactly what your situation is; how did it come about, this "need" to implement a primitive container class?  Is it really cool if you depend on another library?

Everyone else seems to think so, though.  I guess std is really a fundamental component of the C++ language, now....

Looking at other answers, I see std::vector, std::string, std::unique_pointer...

But the road doesn't end there.  Not even close.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class CHashTable {
    typedef std::string KEYTYPE;
    struct HASH_FUNCTOR {
        size_t operator ()(const KEYTYPE& key) const {
            return CHashTable::MyAmazingHashFunc(key);
    }   };
    typename std::unordered_map<KEYTYPE, T, HASH_FUNCTOR> m_um;
public:
    static size_t MyAmazingHashFunc(const KEYTYPE& key) {
        size_t h = key.length();
        for(auto c : key) {
            h = h*143401 + static_cast<size_t>(c)*214517 + 13;
        }
        h = (~h << (sizeof(h)*4)) + (h >> (sizeof(h)*4));
        return h;
    }

    template <typename KT>
    T& operator [] (const KT& key) {
        return m_um[KEYTYPE(key)];
    }
    template <typename KT>
    const T& operator [] (const KT& key) const {
        return m_um.at(KEYTYPE(key));
    }
    void DeleteAll() {
        m_um.clear();
    }
    template <typename KT>
    void Delete(const KT& key) {
        m_um.erase(KEYTYPE(key));
    }
    template <typename KT>
    bool Exists(const KT& key) const {
        const auto fit = m_um.find(KEYTYPE(key));
        return fit != m_um.end();
    }
};

int main() {
    CHashTable<int> ht;
    // my Universal Translator, a "WIP"
    ht["uno"]  = 1;
    ht["un"]   = 1;
    ht["one"]  = 1;
    ht["dos"]  = 2;
    ht["deux"] = 2;
    ht["two"]  = 2;

    const char* key = "deux";
    int value = ht[key];
    std::cout << '[' << key << "] => " << value << std::endl;

    key = "un";
    bool exists = ht.Exists(key);
    std::cout << '[' << key << "]  "
        << (exists ? "exists" : "does not exist") << std::endl;

    key = "trois";
    exists = ht.Exists(key);
    std::cout << '[' << key << "]  "
        << (exists ? "exists" : "does not exist") << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

main()'s output:

```
[deux] => 2
[un]  exists
[trois]  does not exist
```

And that's not even the end of the Hash Table std:: Highway!  The end is abrupt, at a class that just publicly inherits from std::unordered_map.  But I would never suggest THAT in an Answer because I don't want to come across as a sarcastic smartass.